# Bridging two networks

Tags: networking, active-directory, domain, cisco, linksys

I'm hoping you may be able to offer some advice as I'm not very familiar with setting up routers/access points. I have a network of computers on an active directory domain on the 192.NET. I then have another network on the 10.NET that needs to have access to the domain on the 192.NET. I am using cisco/linksys routers. What methodology would you suggest so that these two can communicate and I can add the computers form the 10.NET to the domain?

Edit: Basically, I'm having trouble figuring out how to setup a static route

Comment: You will probably get more relevant answers on Serverfault.com. I'll vote to get this moved to that sub-site. The sysadmins hang around there ;-)

Comment: How are the routers connected?  Is it across the internet, or what.

Comment: Allow me to clarify,

I have network A which receives internet via comcast and has default gateway of 192.168.0.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Network B has default gateway of 10.10.100.1 and subnetmask 255.255.255.0, and this gateway gets its internet via a switch that is connected to 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Why do you have the two networks separated then?  Why not just take the second router out of the loop and connect them all together?

Comment: I would if it was up to me. I'm just trying to find a solution so that I can bridge them. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I know it's not the best way of going about it but if you could offer some insight I'd greatly appreciate it. So far  the linksys E200 keeps spitting out, "INVALID STATIC ROUTE"

Comment: what are the make/model of both routers?

Comment: Jukodan: FYI, bridging has a very specific meaning in the context of networking and in your case, this is not what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the router (and on the interface) 192.168.0.1:

Add a static route to 10.10.100.0 Mask 255.255.255.0 Using 10.10.100.1

In the router (and on the interface) 10.10.100.1:

Add a static route to 192.168.0.0 Mask 255.255.255.0 Using 192.168.0.1

Look at your routers documentation for the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make sure the two routers (gateways) have a common network connection. This might be tricky depending on the equipment you have or your skills. As long as the two routers can ping each other you are good. Then you need to add a static route on router A pointing to router B, for router B's 10.0.100.0 network. And of course on Router B you add a static route pointing for 192.168.0.0 pointing to router A. Your static routes will be preferred, so when a computer on network A needs to talk to network B, it simply will send it's traffic to it's default gateway (router A) which will then forward to router B. By doing this you have created your own routed intranet.

It can be a little difficult doing this with domestic router access points though, as they are really designed to handle the majority case of a single network.